# Parser in Ruby: #slice! inside #each_with_index = missing element

Tags: ruby, parsing, each, slice

Let's say, I want to separate certain combinations of elements from an array. For example

```
data = %w{ start before rgb 255 255 255 between hex FFFFFF after end }
rgb, hex = [], []
data.each_with_index do |v,i|
  p [i,v]
  case v.downcase
    when 'rgb' then rgb  = data.slice! i,4
    when 'hex' then hex  = data.slice! i,2
  end
end
pp [rgb, hex, data]
# >> [0, "start"]
# >> [1, "before"]
# >> [2, "rgb"]
# >> [3, "hex"]
# >> [4, "end"]
# >> [["rgb", "255", "255", "255"],
# >>  ["hex", "FFFFFF"],
# >>  ["start", "before", "between", "after", "end"]]
```

The code have done the correct extraction, but it missed the elements just after the extracted sets. So if my data array is

```
data = %w{ start before rgb 255 255 255 hex FFFFFF after end }
```

then

```
pp [rgb, hex, data]
# >> [["rgb", "255", "255", "255"],
# >>  [],
# >>  ["start", "before", "hex", "FFFFFF", "after", "end"]]
```

Why does it happen? How to get those missed elements inside `#each_with_index`? Or may be there is a better solution for this problem assuming that there are much more sets to extract?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are *mutating* the collection *while* you are iterating over it. This cannot *possibly* work. (And in my opinion, it shouldn't. Ruby should raise an exception in this case, instead of silently allowing incorrect behavior. That's what pretty much all other imperative languages do.)

This here is the best I could come up with while still keeping your original style:

```
require 'pp'

data = %w[start before rgb 255 255 255 hex FFFFFF after end]

rgb_count = hex_count = 0

rgb, hex, rest = data.reduce([[], [], []]) do |acc, el|
  acc.tap do |rgb, hex, rest|
    next (rgb_count = 3  ; rgb << el) if /rgb/i =~ el
    next (rgb_count -= 1 ; rgb << el) if rgb_count > 0
    next (hex_count = 1  ; hex << el) if /hex/i =~ el
    next (hex_count -= 1 ; hex << el) if hex_count > 0
    rest << el
  end
end

data.replace(rest)

pp rgb, hex, data
# ["rgb", "255", "255", "255"]
# ["hex", "FFFFFF"]
# ["start", "before", "after", "end"]
```

However, what you have is a parsing problem and that should really be solved by a parser. A simple hand-rolled parser/state machine will probably be a little bit more code than the above, but it will be *so* much more readable.

Here's a simple recursive-descent parser that solves your problem:

```
class ColorParser
  def initialize(input)
    @input = input.dup
    @rgb, @hex, @data = [], [], []
  end

  def parse
    parse_element until @input.empty?
    return @rgb, @hex, @data
  end

  private

  def parse_element
    parse_color or parse_stop_word
  end

  def parse_color
    parse_rgb or parse_hex
  end

  def parse_rgb
    return unless /rgb/i =~ peek
    @rgb << consume
    parse_rgb_values
  end
```

I really like recursive-descent parsers because their structure almost perfectly matches the grammar: just keep parsing elements until the input is empty. What is an element? Well, it's a color specification or a stop word. What is a color specification? Well, it's either an RGB color specification or a hex color specification. What is an RGB color specification? Well, it's something that matches the Regexp `/rgb/i` followed by RGB values. What are RGB values? Well, it's just three numbers …

```
  def parse_rgb_values
    3.times do @rgb << consume.to_i end
  end

  def parse_hex
    return unless /hex/i =~ peek
    @hex << consume
    parse_hex_value
  end

  def parse_hex_value
    @hex << consume.to_i(16)
  end

  def parse_stop_word
    @data << consume unless /rgb|hex/i =~ peek
  end

  def consume
    @input.slice!(0)
  end

  def peek
    @input.first
  end
end
```

Use it like so:

```
data = %w[start before rgb 255 255 255 hex FFFFFF after end]
rgb, hex, rest = ColorParser.new(data).parse

require 'pp'

pp rgb, hex, rest
# ["rgb", 255, 255, 255]
# ["hex", 16777215]
# ["start", "before", "after", "end"]
```

For comparison, here's the grammar:

- *S* → *element*`*`
- *element* → *color* `|` *word*
- *color* → *rgb* `|` *hex*
- *rgb* → <kbd>rgb</kbd> *rgbvalues*
- *rgbvalues* → **token**  **token**  **token**
- *hex* → <kbd>hex</kbd> *hexvalue*
- *hexvalue* → **token**
- *word* → **token**

Comment: Thanks for the nice example! I need to parse a not very complicated syntax, which is mostly a chain of space-separated words/numbers (mixed sets), although with comments and quoted strings. I am quite a newbie in this problem, so may be you can advise me good libraries/tutorials/examples for making such parsers in Ruby?

Comment: Sweeet!.. Thank you very much for your time, Jörg! Really appreciate your help. The parser looks very nice and clear, but I need some time to think how to add other types of my input. I will probably show up on SO again with another question about the parser.

Comment: @Andrei: if you are a paying member or the ACM or you are a student or employee of a company/school/college/university that is a paying member, you should definitely check out the paper *An object oriented approach to constructing recursive descent parsers* by Matthew S. Davis (http://Portal.ACM.Org/citation.cfm?id=345105.345113). It uses Smalltalk for the examples, but they are mostly directly applicable to Ruby as well.

Comment: @Andrei: also, I found it helpful to have the grammar at least informally written down and put it side-by-side with the code.

Comment: örg: Thank you for the nice reference and advices! I have got the article and tried to read it. Pretty new language for me and quite a number of references to more nice articles. I still have difficulties to write Greibach forms for my grammar. May be you can have a look on it, if you have time? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363227/parser-in-ruby-dealing-with-sticky-comments-and-quotes

Answer (score 1):

Because you are manipulating `data` in place.

When you hit `rgb` the next element in the loop would be `255`, but you are deleting those elements so now `between` is in the place that `rgb` was, so the next element is `hex`

Something like this may work better for you:

```
when 'rgb' then rgb  = data.slice! i+1,3
when 'hex' then hex  = data.slice! i+1,1
```

Comment: I see. How would you do such extraction then? (here, `rgb` and `hex` are just to illustrate the results. I use `color` in my code in both cases)

Comment: Aha,.. no I need to remove 'rgb', 'hex' and others from `data` (case-insensitive)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit nicer solution

```
data = %w{ start before rgb 255 255 255 hex FFFFFF hex EEEEEE after end }
rest, rgb, hex = [], [], []
until data.empty?
  case (key = data.shift).downcase
    when 'rgb' then rgb  += [key] + data.shift(3)
    when 'hex' then hex  += [key] + data.shift(1)
    else rest << key
  end
end
p rgb, hex, rest
# >> ["rgb", "255", "255", "255"]
# >> ["hex", "FFFFFF", "hex", "EEEEEE"]
# >> ["start", "before", "after", "end"]
```