# Parser in Ruby: dealing with sticky comments and quotes

Tags: ruby, parsing, recursive-descent

I am trying to make a recursive-descent parser in Ruby for a grammar, which is defined by the following rules

1. **Input** consists of *white-space* separated **Cards** starting with a **Stop-word**,
   where *white-space* is regex `/[ \n\t]+/`
2. Card may consist of **Keywords** or/and **Values** also separated by white-space, 
   which have card-specific order/pattern
3. All Stop-words and Keywords are case-insensitive, i.e.: `/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*$/i`
4. Value can be a *double-quoted string*, which may be not separated from 
   other words by a white-space, e.g.:

   ```
   word"quoted string"word
   ```
5. Value can be also a *word* `/^[a-z]+[a-z0-9]*$/`, or *integer*, or *float* (e.g. `-1.15`, or `1.0e+2`)
6. *Single-line comment* is denoted by `#` and may be not separated from 
   other words, e.g.:

   ```
   word#single-line comment\n
   ```
7. *Multi-line comment* is denoted by `/*` and `*/` and may be not 
   separated from other words, e.g.:

   ```
   word/*multi-line 
   comment*/word
   ```

---

```
# Input example. Stop-words are chosen just to highlight them: set, object
set title"Input example"set objects 2#not-separated by white-space. test: "/*
set test "#/*"
object 1 shape box/* shape is a Keyword, 
box is a Value. test: "#*/object 2 shape sphere
set data # message and complete are Values
0 0 0 0 1 18 18 18 1 35 35 35 72 35 35 # all numbers are Values of the Card "set"
```

---

Since most of the words are separated by white-space, for a while I was thinking about splitting the whole input and parsing word-by-word. To deal with comments and quotes, I was going to do

```
words = input_text.gsub( /([\"\#\n]|\/\*|\*\/)/, ' \1 ' ).split( /[ \t]+/ )
```

However, in this way the content of strings (and comments, if I want to keep them) is modified. How would you deal with these sticky comments and quotes?

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343726/parser-in-ruby-slice-inside-each-with-index-missing-element

Comment: I don't believe that splitting text on white spaces is a good idea for parsing anything except the really simplest grammars. I don't want to write an essay on creating parsers here... Anyway, google for "compiler compiler ruby", "parser generation ruby"... This is one example http://treetop.rubyforge.org/

Comment: Well, treetop is a bit hard for me to understand. May be you can show me how I can apply it to my grammar? I thought that for such an easy grammar I could make something myself with the kind help of SO users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I made it myself. One can minimize the following code if its readability is not necessary

```
class WordParser
  attr_reader :words

  def initialize text
    @text = text
  end

  def parse
    reset_parser
    until eof?
      case curr_char
        when '"' then
          start_word and add_chars_until? '"'
          close_word
        when '#','%' then
          start_word and add_chars_until? "\n"
          close_word
        when '/' then
          if next_is? '*' then
            start_word and 2.times { add_char }
            add_char until curr_is? '*' and next_is? '/' or eof?
            2.times { add_char } unless eof?
            close_word
          else
            # parser_error "unexpected symbol '/'" # if not allowed in the grammar
            start_word unless word_already_started?
            add_char
          end
        when /[^\s]/ then
          start_word unless word_already_started?
          add_char
      else # skip whitespaces etc. between words
        move and close_word
      end
    end
    return @words
  end

private

  def reset_parser
    @position = 0
    @line, @column = 1, 1
    @words = []
    @word_started = false
  end

  def parser_error s
    Kernel.puts 'Parser error on line %d, col %d: ' + s
    raise 'Parser error'
  end

  def word_already_started?
    @word_started
  end

  def close_word
    @word_started = false
  end

  def add_chars_until? ch
    add_char until next_is? ch or eof?
    2.times { add_char } unless eof?
  end

  def add_char
    @words.last[:to] = @position
    # @words.last[:length] += 1
    # @word.last += curr_char # if one just collects words
    move
  end

  def start_word
    @words.push from: @position, to: @position, line: @line, column: @column
    # @words.push '' unless @words.last.empty? # if one just collects words
    @word_started = true
  end

  def move
    increase :@position
    return if eof?
    if prev_is? "\n"
      increase :@line
      reset :@column
    else
      increase :@column
    end
  end

  def reset var; instance_variable_set(var, 1) end
  def increase var; instance_variable_set(var, instance_variable_get(var)+1) end

  def eof?; @position >= @text.length end

  def prev_is? ch; prev_char == ch end
  def curr_is? ch; curr_char == ch end
  def next_is? ch; next_char == ch end

  def prev_char; @text[ @position-1 ] end
  def curr_char; @text[ @position   ] end
  def next_char; @text[ @position+1 ] end
end
```

Test using the example I have in my question

```
words = WordParser.new(text).parse
p words.collect { |w| text[ w[:from]..w[:to] ] } .to_a

# >> ["# Input example. Stop-words are chosen just to highlight them: set, object\n", 
# >>  "set", "title", "\"Input example\"", "set", "objects", "2", 
# >>  "#not-separated by white-space. test: \"/*\n", "set", "test", "\"#/*\"", 
# >>  "object", "1", "shape", "box", "/* shape is a Keyword, \nbox is a Value. test: \"#*/", 
# >>  "object", "2", "shape", "sphere", "set", "data", "# message and complete are Values\n", 
# >>  "0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "18", "18", "18", "1", "35", "35", "35", "72", 
# >>  "35", "35", "# all numbers are Values of the Card \"set\"\n"]
```

So now I can use [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3343726/parser-in-ruby-slice-inside-each-with-index-missing-element/3388491#3388491) to parse the words further.